# Adding Default Filter in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a new report in CRM2011 and uploaded an RDL file.  Can you let me know how I can create a default filter for this report?  When I try to select "Edit Default Filter", I get the message "This report cannot have a default filter".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable the default CRM filters, you should make sure to have a hidden **Report Parameter** added to your RDL report, that has the following name format: **`CRM_Filtered<EntityName>`**.

E.g. *CRM_FilteredAccount*, for a report based on the Account entity.